# Scrolling a word in the text using RichText and CustomScrollView (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, scroll

While scrolling through webpage on flutter web app, I'm trying to scroll a specific word in a sentence and replace it with another word and so on.

I have tried using CustomScrollView, slivers and Rich Text but getting paintOffset errors in most of the UI I have tried. Below is the current state of my app where in trying to position text through a SliverList so that it coincides with the Pinned text. It does not work for every layout and need a way in it to fade text under the sentence.

FYI - Major tree structure is Layout Builder at the top, followed by PageView, NestedScrollView for this specific page to stop PageView scroll until scrolling of this page completes.

Code:

```
class WhyUsRationaleMould extends StatelessWidget {
  final BoxConstraints constraints;
  final ScrollController? whyUsController;
  final ScrollPhysics scrollPhysics;

  const WhyUsRationaleMould(
      {Key? key,
      required this.constraints,
      required this.whyUsController,
      required this.scrollPhysics})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Size maxSize = Size(constraints.maxWidth, constraints.maxHeight);
    return CustomScrollView(
      controller: whyUsController,
      physics: scrollPhysics,
      slivers: [
        SliverPadding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25.0, top: 45.0),
          sliver: SliverPinnedHeader(
            child: WhyUsContainer(
              maxSize: maxSize,
              child: RichText(
                text: TextSpan(
                  text: 'WORK WITH US\n& WORK WITH THE\n',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.displaySmall?.copyWith(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    shadows: [
                      Shadow(color: Colors.grey, offset: Offset(0, 1.5), blurRadius: 5.0)
                    ],
                  ),
                  children: [
                    TextSpan(
                      text: 'RIGHT ',
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.displaySmall?.copyWith(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        shadows: [
                          Shadow(color: Colors.grey, offset: Offset(0, 1.5), blurRadius: 5.0)
                        ],
                      ),
                      children: [], //Scroll a list of words here
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((BuildContext context, int index) {
            return WhyUsContainer(
              maxSize: Size(maxSize.width, maxSize.height / 2),
              color: Colors.transparent,
              child: RichText(
                textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                text: TextSpan(
                  text: 'No.${index + 1}\n',
                  style: Theme.of(context)
                      .textTheme
                      .headlineMedium
                      ?.copyWith(color: colorRoyalBlue, shadows: [
                    Shadow(color: Colors.grey, offset: Offset(0, 1.5), blurRadius: 5.0),
                  ]),
                  children: [
                    TextSpan(
                      text: WhyUsData.whyUsTitle[index],
                      style: Theme.of(context)
                          .textTheme
                          .displaySmall
                          ?.copyWith(color: colorRoyalBlue, shadows: [
                        Shadow(color: Colors.grey, offset: Offset(0, 1.5), blurRadius: 5.0),
                      ]),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          }, childCount: WhyUsData.whyUsTitle.length),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class WhyUsContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  final Size maxSize;
  final Widget child;
  final Color? color;

  WhyUsContainer({Key? key, required this.maxSize, required this.child, this.color})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: maxSize.height <= 70.0 ? maxSize.height : maxSize.height - 70.0,
      //Subtracting Appbar Height 70.0
      width: maxSize.width,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(28.0),
      color: color == null ? Colors.transparent : color,
      child: child,
    );
  }
}

class SliverWhyUsRationale extends SingleChildRenderObjectWidget {
  SliverWhyUsRationale({Key? key, required Widget child}) : super(child: child, key: key);

  @override
  RenderObject createRenderObject(BuildContext context) {
    return RenderWhyUsMould();
  }
}

class RenderWhyUsMould extends RenderSliverSingleBoxAdapter {
  RenderWhyUsMould({RenderBox? child}) : super(child: child);

  @override
  void performLayout() {
    if (child == null) {
      geometry = SliverGeometry.zero;
      return;
    }
    final SliverConstraints constraints = this.constraints;
    child!.layout(constraints.asBoxConstraints(), parentUsesSize: true);
    final double childExtent;
    switch (constraints.axis) {
      case Axis.horizontal:
        childExtent = child!.size.width;
      case Axis.vertical:
        childExtent = child!.size.height;
    }
    final double paintedChildSize =
        calculatePaintOffset(constraints, from: 0.0, to: childExtent);
    geometry = SliverGeometry(
      scrollExtent: childExtent / 2,
      paintExtent: paintedChildSize,
      //paintOrigin: constraints.scrollOffset + 40.0,
      maxPaintExtent: childExtent + 25.0,
    );
    setChildParentData(child!, constraints, geometry!);
  }
}
```

Comment: Anyone has ideas to try here? thanks.