addListener on scroll controller to animateTo an offset is not working
While trying to create a snap effect on the header of a ReorderableListView, I have written below code. But the jobWidgetListener function is not animating my list items to the required offset.
In the State of my StatefulWidget, I have
 final ScrollController _reorderScrollController = ScrollController();

 static const _processItemWidth = 150.0;
 void jobWidgetListener() {
    if (_reorderScrollController.hasClients) {

      if (_reorderScrollController.position.extentBefore < _processItemWidth * 0.8) {
        print('this');
        _reorderScrollController.animateTo(
          0.0,
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 350),
          curve: Curves.easeOut,
        );
      } else if (_reorderScrollController.position.extentBefore < _processItemWidth) {
        print('that');
        _reorderScrollController.animateTo(
          _processItemWidth + 8.0,
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 350),
          curve: Curves.easeOut,
        );
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => _scrollToIndex(_activeProcessIndex)); // <- this one scrolls to active item in my list on rebuild and is working fine, so not providing details here
    _reorderScrollController.addListener(jobWidgetListener); // <-- Listener added here
  }

The print statements in the jobWidgetListener function are printed in console correctly.
In the build function, I have
ReorderableListView.builder(
                header: Container(
                    width: _processItemWidth, decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blue)),
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                scrollController: _reorderScrollController,
                cacheExtent: _processItemWidth * _activeProcessIndex > 300.0
                    ? _processItemWidth * _activeProcessIndex
                    : 300.0,
                onReorder: (int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
                  _updateProcessOrder(
                      oldIndex: oldIndex,
                      newIndex: newIndex,
                      oldProcess: widget.jobs.process,
                      jobID: widget.jobs.jid);
                },
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return ProcessItemWidget(
                      key: ValueKey(processItem[index].name),
                      width: _processItemWidth,
                      index: index,
                      processItem: processItem,
                      jid: widget.jobs.jid);
                },
                itemCount: widget.jobs.process.length,
              ),


"While trying to create a snap effect on the header of a ReorderableLietView" - most likely you need a custom ScrollPhysics for that - for example check how PageScrollPhysics is snapping its pages here

So, something like if position or offset is near header then use custom scroll physics else normal ? I want the header to be always hidden underneath another widget (Container in my case), unless user force pulls the header out to perform some action using buttons on header of the list. So if user scrolls to start of the list, then again user should give another scroll to get header out. Thanks for your hint.

but if you need such a dynamic header why don you use CustomScrollView + SliverPersisentHeader (or SliverAppBar) + SliverReorderableList?

There are multiple horizontal reorderable lists inside ListView.custom. So this top page of my app is like grid scrollable in both directions with many other features/complexities. I played with those Slivers in some other part of my App and got stuck. I will again take a look if those can replace my current setup.

perhaps, it was this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77112807/scrolling-a-word-in-the-text-using-richtext-and-customscrollview-flutter Anyways, will look into those again.

seems i overlooked that you want "a snap effect on the header", and now i dont understand how with _reorderScrollController.animateTo you would show / hide the header? it would animate the list content, not header

This issue is with the reorderableListView component, it is possible that the scrollController you passed in was not used
